# How resize the left image on the NSIS installer?

Tags: nsis

NSIS automaticaly resizes the image to 150x57 I think. But my image is 175x100 how I can prevent NSIS from deforming it ? 
I'm using this define :

`!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "myImage"`

I found AddBrandingImage but i don't think it il what I'm looking for. I will test anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NSIS 3 you can try `!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_STRETCH AspectFitHeight`.

If you want to use a larger image without resizing it then you must modify the UI (NSIS\Contrib\UIs\Modern.exe) with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and apply it with [ChangeUI](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/ChangeUI).